# Query relating to marginal pdf (probability density function)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I have a set of two related queries relating to marginal pdfs:

i.How to proceed finding  the marginal pdfs of two independent  gamma distributions (X1 and X2) with parameters (α1,β) and  (α2,β) respectively, given the transformation:
Y1=X1/(X1+X2) and Y2=X1+X2.

I am using the following gamma formula:

[image: Image 1]

Having written the joint pdf and having applied the Jacobean, I have reached the final stage of writing the expression for the marginal (Y1):

[image: Image 2]

but I cannot  proceed further, obtaining the marginal pdf.

ii.Additionally, given the following transformations , Y1=X1/X2 and Y2=X2, I have written the expression for the marginal  (Y2):

[image: Image 3]

How do I find this marginal pdf?

Any enlightening answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression for the first part doesn't seem correct.  If
$$y_1=\frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2}, ~~~y_2=x_1+x_2$$ Then $$x_1=y_1y_2, ~~ x_2=y_2(1-y_1) $$ Then, for the Jacobian, $$|J|=y_2$$
Since for the gamma distribution you have that $x_1>0, x_2>0$, it implies that the new support is $y_2>0, ~~0<y_1<1$

By independence, the joint pdf of $X_1, X_2$ is
$$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1, x_2)=\frac{\beta^{\alpha_1}}{\Gamma(\alpha_1)}x_1^{\alpha_1-1}e^{-\beta x_1} \frac{\beta^{\alpha_2}}{\Gamma(\alpha_2)}x_2^{\alpha_2-1}e^{-\beta x_2}$$

By the bivariate transformation,
$$\begin{align} f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)&=f_{X_1,X_2}(y_1y_2,y_2(1-y_1))|J|
\\&= \frac{\beta^{\alpha_1}}{\Gamma(\alpha_1)}(y_1y_2)^{\alpha_1-1}e^{-\beta (y_1y_2)} \frac{\beta^{\alpha_2}}{\Gamma(\alpha_2)}(y_2(1-y_1))^{\alpha_2-1}e^{-\beta (y_2(1-y_1))}y_2\\ 
&= \ldots \\&= \frac{\beta^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}}{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)}y_2^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2 -1}e^{-\beta y_2}y_1^{\alpha_1-1}(1-y_1)^{\alpha_2-1}\end{align}$$
Now while you can indeed use the integration technique to get the marginal PDF, an easier but not-so-obvious technique to use here is realize that:

1) $f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)$ can be factored into a product of 2 functions of $y_1$ only, and of $y_2$ only: $f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)=g(y_1)h(y_2)$

2) and the support of $(Y_1,Y_2)$ is a Cartesian product since $0<y_1<0$ and $y_2>0$ (forms a rectangular support)

These 2 statements imply that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent. 
However, to get a product of 2 PDFs, we need the normalization constants, so we multiply the top and bottom by $\color{red}{\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)}$ (this is motivated by the fact that $h(y_2)$ looks like a gamma PDF). By doing that and a slight re-arrangement, you get:
$$f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)= \underbrace{\frac{\beta^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}}{\color{red}{\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)}}y_2^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2 -1}e^{-\beta y_2}}_{f_{Y_2}(y_2)}~\underbrace{\frac{\color{red}{\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)}}{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)}y_1^{\alpha_1-1}(1-y_1)^{\alpha_2-1}}_{f_{Y_1}(y_1)}$$
Where $f_{Y_2}(y_2)$ is the PDF for the $Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2, \beta)$ distribution for $y_2>0$, and $f_{Y_1}(y_1)$ is the PDF for the $Beta(\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$ distribution for $0<y_1<1$.